# Understanding Jetsam Log "proc-thrashing"

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that uses location services in the background continuously and once in a while it will be terminated without any crash log being generated. I assume that the app is being terminated by the system to recapture memory. I notice that my app only sometimes has a "reason" tag under its process. If a process has the reason tag does that mean that during this jetsam event that process was terminated?

My application and several others have the "proc-thrashing" reason, can anyone explain how to avoid this or how to deal with it?

Does "purgeable:0" mean that the app is not supposed to be purged from memory?

Below is from a jetsam event log:

```
"states" : [
  "location"
],
"killDelta" : 1488764,
"genCount" : 8,
"age" : 45709913917,
"purgeable" : 0,
"fds" : 50,
"coalition" : 5191,
"rpages" : 2382,
"reason" : "proc-thrashing",
"pid" : 27026,
"cpuTime" : 15.933816999999999,
"name" : "My app",
"lifetimeMax" : 7051
```

}

Comment: I solved this problem by making sure that my app didn't use more than 20% CPU time for more than 60 seconds. I believe those are the current Apple rules